# Figma Relay Import Error Transformation Error

Tags: android, android-studio, relayjs, figma

I attempted to import some themes that were on figma into my android studio using Relay. When importing, I put in my link and left the theme as: `androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme`

I got an error with this stacktrace:

```
com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaServiceException: Command:
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\plugins\relay_android_studio\bin\win64\figma_to_adin

Stack Trace:
Severe: Failed to transform https://www.figma.com/file/{redacted}/{redacted}?type=design&node-id=7-400&mode=design&t={redacted}:

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
#0      _$VectorNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:611)
#1      new VectorNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:861)
#2      ContainerNode._childFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:449)
#3      ContainerNode.childrenFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:463)
#4      _$InstanceNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:290)
#5      new InstanceNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:567)
#6      ContainerNode._childFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:451)
#7      ContainerNode.childrenFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:463)
#8      _$FrameNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:455)
#9      new FrameNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:759)
#10     ContainerNode._childFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:442)
#11     ContainerNode.childrenFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:463)
#12     _$FrameNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:455)
#13     new FrameNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:759)
#14     ContainerNode._childFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:442)
#15     ContainerNode.childrenFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:463)
#16     _$FrameNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:455)
#17     new FrameNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:759)
#18     ContainerNode._childFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:442)
#19     ContainerNode.childrenFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:463)
#20     _$InstanceNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:290)
#21     new InstanceNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:567)
#22     ContainerNode._childFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:451)
#23     ContainerNode.childrenFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:463)
#24     _$FrameNodeFromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.g.dart:455)
#25     new FrameNode.fromJson (package:figma_to_adin/src/figmarest.dart:759)
#26     FigmaRestDataResolver._resolveFrom (package:figma_to_adin/src/figma_data.dart:339)
#27     FigmaRestDataResolver.resolveAll (package:figma_to_adin/src/figma_data.dart:309)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     resolveUIPackagesSet (package:figma_to_adin/src/figma_resolver.dart:45)
<asynchronous suspension>
#29     main (file:///t:/src/git/relay/figma_to_adin/bin/figma_to_adin.dart:120)
<asynchronous suspension>


    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaService.importFile(FigmaService.kt:288)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaService.importPackagesToTemp(FigmaService.kt:143)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaImportWorker.doInBackground(FigmaImportWorker.java:89)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.importer.FigmaImportWorker.doInBackground(FigmaImportWorker.java:44)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I am new to this and would love some help!

Thanks!